# Codeigniter (Inserting category data into table)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter, I carried out an e-commerce project left by the former developer. The case is that the category data is not inserting into my table.

The code is very long in both controller and model but I cut it out and posted only the necessary part of it.

This is my controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Category extends Admin_Controller {
public function create()
    {
        /* Breadcrumbs */
        $this->breadcrumbs->unshift(2, "New Category" , 'admin/category/create');
        $this->data['breadcrumb'] = $this->breadcrumbs->show();

        /* Variables */
        $tables = $this->config->item('tables', 'ion_auth');

        /* Validate form input */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat_name', 'Category Name', 'trim|required');       



        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {

            $config['upload_path'] =  './assets/uploads/category/';
            //die(var_dump(is_dir($config['upload_path'])));
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'png,jpeg';
            $config['max_size']    = '1024';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $img = "icon";
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($img))
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
                redirect('admin/category');
            }
            else
            {
                $data=$this->upload->data();
                $file = array('file_name' => $data['file_name'] );

                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $photo = base_url().'assets/uploads/category/'.$file['file_name'];

                $data = array(
                    'category_name' => $this->input->post('cat_name'),
                    'category_photo'  => $photo,
                    'category_description'    => $this->input->post('cat_desc')
                );

                $this->category_model->insertcategory($data);
                //$this->ion_auth->messages()
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "Successfully inserted!");
                redirect('admin/category', 'refresh');
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));           

            /* Load Template */
            $this->template->admin_render('admin/category/create', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

This is my model.

```
class Category_model extends CI_Model
{
function insertcategory($data) {

        $query = $this->db->insert('category', $data);

        if ($query) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is my form.

```
<div class="box-body">
                                    <span style="color:red"><?php echo $message;?></span>

                                    <?php echo form_open_multipart(current_url(), array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'form-create_user')); ?>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <span class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</span> 
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cat_name" placeholder="Category Name" name="cat_name" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <span class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Description</span> 
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cat_desc" placeholder="Description" name="cat_desc" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <span class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Icon</span> 
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input class="input-file uniform_on" id="icon" name="icon" type="file">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                    <?php echo form_button(array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-flat', 'content' => lang('actions_submit'))); ?>
                                                    <?php echo form_button(array('type' => 'reset', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-flat', 'content' => lang('actions_reset'))); ?>
                                                    <?php echo anchor('admin/category', lang('actions_cancel'), array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-flat')); ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php echo form_close();?>
                                </div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please replace **$img = "icon";** with **$img = $this->input->post('icon');**

Please check with the above data.

Also please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: This is the problem, it doesn't show any error message. After filling and submitting it just go to index page without showing error and inserting data in the table. I try ur option but i don't work too though thz you man.